# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on API level 11

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing an error whilst using API level 11.

My app crashes with the following:   `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.question.question.BitmapCache` only when I use my app with a device running api level 11:

I have Google'd this ofcourse and have tried every solution I have came across but still no luck.

Here is the line where it says there's a problem with in Logcat:

```
    public GoogleCardsAdapter(final Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mMemoryCache = new BitmapCache();  //<---- This line here
}
```

Here's the bitmap cache class:

```
public class BitmapCache extends LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> {

private static final int KILO = 1024;
private static final int MEMORY_FACTOR = 2 * KILO;

public BitmapCache() {
    super((int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / MEMORY_FACTOR));
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(final Integer key, final Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / KILO;
}
     }
```

I am using a few libs as well:

[image]

[image]

If anyone knows what is going wrong here, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, you are trying to [use `android.util.LruCache`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html), which only exists in API Level 12 and above.

Consider switching to [`android.support.v4.util.LruCache` from the Android Support package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html), which will work going back to API Level 4.

Also, please undo your manual modifications of your build path, and copy the Picasso and ListViewAnimations JARs into your project's `libs/` directory, so the JARs are on both your build path *and* packaged into the APK for distribution.

Comment: Good answer, but the build path comment sounds entitled and is unrelated to the question.

Comment: @SamDozor: It was an obvious problem, one that may well cause this developer to return to Stack Overflow seeking help yet again, when those libraries fail to work at runtime because they are not in the APK.

Comment: Agreed, and I'm aware it was obvious. I was suggesting (1) that you avoid using a condescending tone, and (2) if he did run into that problem down the line and came here to resolve it, we'd then have another useful question and answer for the community, whereas now it will be hidden within this, an unrelated question and answer.